# How to work with plist file using GCD safely?

Tags: objective-c, plist, grand-central-dispatch

I have a simple application which stores its data in plist file, and I need to work with this data. So the process of storing the data takes about 5 seconds (artificial delay for studying proposes) and at the same time I need to read the data of the plist (for example to show it in the second screen).

So first of all I moved the save method in

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{});
```

and the read method in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{});
```

but I think that it can cause problems when I tried to read the plist during the saving process.

Anyway I don't need to freeze the screens. How to make the I/O process for the plist correctly  in several threads? May be I should use two different queues for read/write? How to synchronize them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tip: Improve Performance with Reader-Writer Access

• Use concurrent subsystem queue

- DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT

• Use synchronous concurrent “reads”

- dispatch_sync()

• Use asynchronous serialized “writes”

- dispatch_barrier_async()

Example:

```
// ...
   _someManagerQueue = dispatch_queue_create("SomeManager", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
// ...
```

You could create your queue on init, awake for nib, etc... Use dispatch_once if the function can be called more than once in the same instance.

Then:

```
 - (id) getSomeArrayItem:(NSUInteger) index {
    id importantObj = NULL;
    dispatch_sync(_someManagerQueue,^{
        id importantObj = [_importantArray objectAtIndex:index];
     });
   return importantObj;
 }
- (void) removeSomeArrayItem:(id) object {
     dispatch_barrier_async(_someManagerQueue,^{
         [_importantArray removeObject:object];
     });
 }
- (void) addSomeArrayItem:(id) object {
     dispatch_barrier_async(_someManagerQueue,^{
         [_importantArray addObject:object];
     });
 }
```

That way you ensure that whenever you read an information (eg an array) all the "changes" have been made ​​or are "waiting"
. And every time you write an information, your program will not be blocked waiting for the operation to be completed.

You can use serial queues, however it is a huge waste of processing and time does not parallelize the readings. That way, if you use several threads, none will have to wait another unless it is "write", which is right.

More information about: WWDC 2012 Session 712

Answer (score 1):

You should use a single, serial queue for both reading and writing. That way, you're ensured that they won't interfere with each other.

For example, in `viewDidLoad` you could create your queue:

```
self.queue = dispatch_queue_create(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
```

And then you can use it when saving:

```
dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
    // save
});
```

and when reading:

```
dispatch_async(self.queue, ^{
    // read
});
```

This is one of the primary purposes of serial queues, to synchronize the access to some shared resource (see the [discussion of serial queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1)).

Comment: OK, I'll try to use the serial queue and will write the result later, thank u!